# How to access the viewmodel of a dynamically added UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Scenario is something like this,
I am having a *MainWindow.xaml* where as part of this window I will load a UserControl.
This UserControl is actually in some other project and it is added in a ResourceDictionary with a key as below,

```
<ContentControl x:Key="Template1">
    <customcontrol:Template1UserControl/>
</ContentControl>
```

So in *MainWindow.xaml* I will refer this key as below,

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Template1}"/>
```

Now, like this I am able to see the *Template1UserControl* in *MainWindow.xaml*, but the problem is I don't know how to access the datacontext of *Template1UserControl* in *MainWindow.xaml*.

*Template1* is like a variable, it can have *Template2UserControl* tomorrow, which can be anything.

Can anyone please help me to do this in WPF.
If I should apply some other strategy over here to access the viewmodel of *Template1UserControl*, that also is most welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A UserControl wrapped in a ContentControl, wrapped in yet another ContentControl? Looks odd. The UserControl should instead be declared in a DataTemplate. You would assign an instance of the view model type to the Content property of a ContentControl, and the appropriate DataTemplate (with a DataType that matches the view model type) would be chosen automatically. To make this work, the UserControl must not set its own DataContext, i.e. have a private view model.

Comment: What do you want access exactly? Btw, the usage looks like you are making *custom* control, those don't need view model, rather a set of dependency properties. ViewModel (MVVM) makes sense to have if something will be datatemplated, which is other way around: you will rather have a view model instance at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Give the `ContentControl` in the `MainWindow` an `x:Name`:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="cc" Content="{StaticResource Template1}"/>
```

...and try to cast the properties:

```
var theTemplate = cc.Content as ContentControl;
var theUserControl = theTemplate?.Content as UserControl;
var theDataContext = theUserControl?.DataContext;
```